# Nested one-liner loops

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, python-3.x, for-loop

I know how to write one-liner loops, with one loop, such as

```
for x in range(0,10): print(x)
```

But I want something like

```
for x in range(0,10): if 1==1: print(x)
```

However, this returns an error. How could I fix that?

Comment: You fix it by putting it on multiple lines ;) Or, more seriously, you could refactor to a list comprehension, something like `for y in (x for x in range(0, 10) if 1==1): print(y)`

Comment: @MagnusHoff That is called a generator expression, not list comprehension :D

Comment: Or just forget about the one-liner. Redability counts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Py3 you can do

```
for x in range(0,10): print(x) if 1==1 else None
```

Output

```
>>> for x in range(0,10): print(x) if 1==1 else None
... 
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Comment: This will print `None` for those values where the condition does not apply. It's basically `print ( (x) if condition else None)` For Python3, it works better, as `print` is a function, then.

Comment: @tobias_k The OP can put anything there. Thanks for the info though

Comment: @BhargavRao: But you have to put *something* there.  In Python 2, you can't print nothing, which is what is desired here.  (Unless you use `from __future__ import print_fucntion`, available for 2.6+)